# How to define a self executing Javascript function

Tags: javascript

Is there any way by which we can define a self executing javascript function?
I mean execute a function automatically when the page renders ,without calling it .

Comment: Your question makes no sense, execute and call are synonyms. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I think you're looking for an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ('IIFE')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which is what sza's answer shows; though reading Quentin's comment I may have perhaps misunderstood your question.

Comment: Googling "javascript auto execute function" counts as the basic research you should do before asking.

Comment: He is not looking for functions that execute as soon as they are defined. Read the question text, people, not just the title.

Comment: @Renan He wants to execute a function without calling it, which - as Quentin pointed out - is utter nonsense, since calling a function and executing a function are the same thing. Your interpretation of the question is no more valid than any other because the question is garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(function(){
    //your stuff
})();
```

or

```
(function(params){
    //your stuff
})(params);
```

Comment: Nope. That calls a function right after declaring it, but it does not necessarily execute a function after a page is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Put you functions codes on body onload or document ready if you are using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you just write a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo();
</script>
```

It will execute as soon as possible. Otherwise you can execute something as soon as the page loads, by eithe rusing the `onload` attribute of a form, or by using [`jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).